# Is there any way/alternative to readlink -f in Linux to handle spaces present in the folder name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My directory structure is /local/mnt/abcd/sub 1

So inside the 'sub 1' folder, I am trying to execute the following script

```
SOURCEDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
readlink -f $SOURCEDIR/..
```

it gives output as : /local/mnt/abcd/sub not /local/mnt/abcd/sub\ 1
Basically, it is not able to handle if there is a space present in the folder name. So I want to know is there any alternative to readlink or any other way we can get the absolute path

Comment: *Always* quote parameter expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the parameter expansion so that `readlink` gets the path as a single argument.

```
readlink -f "$SOURCEDIR/.."
```

Without the quotes, it's equivalent to

```
readlink -f /local/mnt/abcd/sub 1/..
```

Answer (score 2):

Put double-quotes round the argument to keep it as a single argument:

```
readlink -f "$SOURCEDIR/.."
```